# why does overflow occurs?

Tags: html, css

I've changed my question because I narrowed the cause of problem:

```
  <div id="wrapper" class="centrDiv clearfix">
            <div id="LEFT-CONTAINER">
                <div id="logo" class="centrSlik">
                    <img src="wheel.gif"/>
                </div>
                <div id="podmeni">
                    <ul><li><a>whatever</a></li></ul>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="RIGHT-CONTAINER">
            <div id="meni">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='whatever'>whatever</a></li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="tekst">
                <p>whatever</p>
                ...
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS that describes it:

```
#wrapper{max-width: 1000px; margin-top: 15px; background: #99CCCC;}
#menu{overflow:auto;background: #FF9999; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 20px; border-bottom-right-radius:20px 10px; border: 1px solid #FF9999; opacity:0.9;}
#LEFT-CONTAINER{float: left; background-color: #71637D;}
```

My question is why does `#RIGHT-CONTAINER` overflows `div#menu`?
I know how to fix it, but wish to know why does overflow occurs.

Thanks!

[image: screen capture]

Comment: you need to post your code of html and css to see what is going on

Comment: Just a guess without seeing your real HTML... try using "display: inline-block" instead of floats.

Comment: Your JsFiddle code is in a different language and needs to be stripped of all distracting information.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba, it's still not clear to me what you are asking. Maybe try explaining (1) what you expect to happen in your code and (2) how what actually happens is different.

Answer (score 2):

floating a container takes it out of the "flow", similar to positioning absolute.

see these references:

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

what you can do is place `overflow:hidden` on the element you don't want to conflict with the float.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `float:left;` both `#left-container` and `#right-container` or at least, `float:right;` `#right-container`, also remember to clear your floats

Comment: Why in this I need to? `overflow:hidden` makes it work, but I still lack understanding of why does it sometimes overflow and sometimes not. This is not my first time to make multicolumn site with floats. One left float was enough, without overflow to be controlled. I have put the complete code in above post. If you have time check it out please. Thanks

Comment: This answer doesn't allow a flexible width for the right column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your right container is not absolutely positioned I would set a margin-left on it equal to the width of your left-container, in this case 130px. That means that you wouldn't have to worry about all the clears and all of the elements on your page floating.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is a relatively poor tool for creating column layouts, unfortunately. Take a look at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/ for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from @Joseph and @PCasagrande and elaborating…

Applying `float: left` to `#left-container` takes it out of the flow, which essentially means all other non-floated [block](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/display.php) content is no longer aware that it exists. Therefore, `#right-container`, a block element, does what it normally does when there's no other content around and fills the width of its container.

An important thing to note is that inline content does get out of the way of floats. This is why in your screenshot the content inside of `#right-container` is placed right of `#left-container` while the background of `#right-container` ends up behind `#left-container`. See an example at http://jsbin.com/eyusew/edit#html,live.

By simply putting a left margin on `#right-container` equal to the width of the float, you essentially create some space for the float. An example: http://jsbin.com/iqufiw/2/edit#html,live. Notice that now the content in `#right-container` is moved to the right regardless of the presence of the float: http://jsbin.com/iqufiw/3/edit#html,live.

Side note: You will most likely want to apply some sort of [clearfix CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/9932508#9932508) to #wrapper.